# Differences in the standard error of parameters computed via the hessian inverse and via QR decomposition

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, minimization, jax

I have solved a nonlinear optimization and I am trying to compute the standard error of the parameters obtained. I found two options: One uses the fractional covariance matrix formed from the inverse of the hessian while the other uses QR decomposition. However both errors are not the same. The standard error obtained via QR is less than that obtained from the hessian inverse. I am at a loss as to how and why both approaches differ and would like to understand better which is the more correct way. Below is the working example

```
# import libraries
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp  
import jaxopt
jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)


# Create data
F =  jnp.asarray([1.00e-01, 1.30e-01, 1.69e-01, 2.20e-01, 2.86e-01, 3.71e-01,
             4.83e-01, 6.27e-01, 8.16e-01, 1.06e+00, 1.38e+00, 1.79e+00,
             2.33e+00, 3.03e+00, 3.94e+00, 5.12e+00, 6.65e+00, 8.65e+00,
             1.12e+01, 1.46e+01, 1.90e+01, 2.47e+01, 3.21e+01, 4.18e+01,
             5.43e+01, 7.06e+01, 9.17e+01, 1.19e+02, 1.55e+02, 2.02e+02,
             2.62e+02, 3.41e+02, 4.43e+02, 5.76e+02, 7.48e+02, 9.73e+02,
             1.26e+03, 1.64e+03, 2.14e+03, 2.78e+03, 3.61e+03, 4.70e+03,
             6.10e+03, 7.94e+03, 1.03e+04, 1.34e+04, 1.74e+04, 2.27e+04,
             2.95e+04, 3.83e+04, 4.98e+04, 6.47e+04, 8.42e+04, 1.09e+05],dtype=jnp.float64)

ydata = jnp.asarray([45.1  -1.09j, 47.5  -1.43j, 46.8  -1.77j, 46.2  -2.29j,
             46.2  -2.97j, 47.2  -3.8j , 47.   -4.85j, 45.1  -5.99j,
             45.8  -7.33j, 42.3  -9.05j, 42.6 -10.2j , 36.5 -10.8j ,
             34.5 -11.2j , 32.1 -10.2j , 30.   -9.18j, 29.4  -8.j  ,
             27.3  -6.64j, 26.7  -5.18j, 25.3  -4.12j, 25.4  -3.26j,
             25.2  -2.51j, 24.9  -1.94j, 24.9  -1.64j, 25.4  -1.35j,
             25.5  -1.24j, 24.8  -1.1j , 24.7  -1.03j, 23.9  -1.04j,
             25.2  -1.1j , 24.9  -1.27j, 25.   -1.46j, 25.4  -1.65j,
             24.4  -1.98j, 24.5  -2.34j, 24.5  -2.91j, 23.8  -3.47j,
             22.9  -4.13j, 22.3  -4.91j, 20.9  -5.66j, 20.3  -6.03j,
             18.4  -6.96j, 17.6  -7.24j, 16.5  -7.74j, 14.3  -7.42j,
             12.7  -7.17j, 11.2  -6.76j,  9.85 -5.89j,  8.68 -5.38j,
              7.92 -4.53j,  7.2  -3.83j,  6.81 -3.2j ,  6.65 -2.67j,
              6.11 -2.16j,  5.86 -1.77j], dtype=jnp.complex128)

sigma = jnp.asarray([45.11316992, 47.52152039, 46.83345919, 46.25671951,
             46.29536586, 47.35271903, 47.24957672, 45.49604488,
             46.38285136, 43.25728262, 43.8041094 , 38.06428772,
             36.27244133, 33.68159735, 31.37311588, 30.46900064,
             28.09590006, 27.19783815, 25.63326745, 25.6083502 ,
             25.32469348, 24.97545996, 24.95394959, 25.43585068,
             25.53013122, 24.82438317, 24.72146638, 23.92261691,
             25.22399651, 24.93236651, 25.04259571, 25.4535361 ,
             24.48020425, 24.61149325, 24.67221312, 24.05162988,
             23.26944133, 22.83414329, 21.65284277, 21.17665932,
             19.67235624, 19.03096424, 18.22519136, 16.11044382,
             14.58420036, 13.08195704, 11.47669813, 10.21209087,
              9.12399584,  8.15529889,  7.52436708,  7.16598912,
              6.48056325,  6.12147858], dtype=jnp.float64)

# Define Model
def rrpwrcwo(p, x):
    w = 2*jnp.pi*x
    s = 1j*w
    Rs = p[0]
    Qh = p[1]
    nh = p[2]
    Rct = p[3]
    C1 = p[4]
    R1 = p[5]
    Y1 = s*C1 + 1/R1
    Z1 = 1/Y1
    Zct = Rct + Z1
    Ydl = (s**nh)*Qh
    Yin = Ydl + 1/Zct
    Zin = 1/Yin
    Z = Rs + Zin
    return jnp.concatenate((Z.real, Z.imag),axis = 0)


# Define cost function
def obj_fun(p, x, y, yerr, lb, ub):
    ndata = len(x)
    dof = (2*ndata-(len(p)))
    y_concat = jnp.concatenate([y.real, y.imag], axis = 0)
    sigma = jnp.concatenate([yerr,yerr], axis = 0)
    y_model = rrpwrcwo(p, x)
    chi_sqr = (1/dof)*(jnp.sum(jnp.abs((1/sigma**2) * (y_concat - y_model)**2)))
    return chi_sqr

# Define minimization function
def cnls(p, x, y, yerr, lb, ub):
    """
    """
    solver = jaxopt.ScipyMinimize(method = 'BFGS', fun= obj_fun)
    sol = solver.run(p, x, y, yerr, lb, ub)
    # Compute popt
    return sol

# Define initial values and bounds
p0 = jnp.asarray([5, 0.000103, 1, 20, 0.001, 20])

lb = jnp.zeros(len(p0))
lb=lb.at[2].set(0.1)
ub = jnp.full((len(p0),),jnp.inf)
ub.at[2].set(1.01)

# Run optimization
res = cnls(p0, F, ydata, sigma, lb, ub)
popt = res.params
# DeviceArray([5.26589219e+00, 7.46288724e-06, 8.27089860e-01,
#              1.99066599e+01, 3.40764484e-03, 2.19277541e+01],dtype=float64)

# Get the weighted residual mean square
chisqr = res.state.fun_val
# 0.00020399

# Method 1: Error computation using the fractional covariance matrix

# get hessian matrix from parameters at the minimum
hess = jax.jacfwd(jax.jacrev(obj_fun))(popt, F, ydata, sigma, lb, ub)

# Take the hessian inv
hess_inv = jnp.linalg.inv(hess)

# Form the fractional covariance matrix
cov_mat = hess_inv * chisqr

# Compute standard error of the parameters
perr = jnp.sqrt(jnp.diag(cov_mat))
perr
# DeviceArray([4.60842608e-01, 3.64957208e-06, 4.59190021e-02,
#              8.29162454e-01, 4.47488639e-04, 1.49346052e+00], dtype=float64)


# Method 2: Error Computation using QR Decomposition

# Compute gradient of function (model) with respect to the parameters
grads = jax.jacfwd(rrpwrcwo)(popt, F)
gradsre = grads[:len(F)]
gradsim = grads[len(F):]

# Form diagonal weight matrices
rtwre = jnp.diag((1/sigma))
rtwim = jnp.diag((1/sigma))

vre = rtwre@gradsre
vim = rtwim@gradsim

# Compute QR decomposition
Q1, R1 = jnp.linalg.qr(jnp.concatenate([vre,vim], axis = 0))

# Compute inverse of R1
invR1 = jnp.linalg.inv(R1)

# Compute standard error of the parameters
perr = jnp.linalg.norm(invR1, axis=1)*jnp.sqrt(chisqr)
perr

# DeviceArray([6.48631283e-02, 5.14577571e-07, 6.48070403e-03,
#              1.16523404e-01, 6.28434098e-05, 2.09238133e-01],dtype=float64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is you are computing the hessian of a chi-square per degree of freedom, when you should be computing the hessian of chi-square. If you change this line:

```py
chi_sqr = (1/dof)*(jnp.sum(jnp.abs((1/sigma**2) * (y_concat - y_model)**2)))
```

to this:

```py
chi_sqr = 0.5 * (jnp.sum(jnp.abs((1/sigma**2) * (y_concat - y_model)**2)))
```

then the two approaches return approximately the same results.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeees! I get now. Thanks